# How to disable basic http auth for OPTIONS with SpringBoot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have small rest service that is protected with default Spring Boot security config. It by default requires authorization on every http method including OPTIONS, chrome however does not give a flying duck and won't include authorization header in preflight request which results in 401 response.

How can I disable http basic auth on specific method? So far I tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Config {
}
```

And in controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"}, maxAge = 4800)
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
    public ResponseEntity handle() {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Did not work obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
```

add

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/path/to/skip/check").permitAll()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Had to look for .antMatchers method that took HttpMethod, tho. My final solution looks like this: `http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();`

Comment: This does not work in a two-way SSL configuration with x509 client certificate authentication.

Comment: Make sure to put this sequency of function calls on the `http` object at the beginning of all calls on the `http` object, because the order of these rules matter, and the `permitAll()` rules should tend to go first.